# Arch + AwesomeWM -> How to configure keybindings

Tags: arch-linux, awesome-wm

I just switched to awesomewm. I am however wondering how can I:

1. Make left Alt be Mod4 too (so both LAlt and Meta are Mod4)
2. Make CapsLock become Escape

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In order to map Caps Lock to Escape you can add the following to your .xinitrc:

> setxkbmap -option caps:escape &

I couldn't manage to map Alt though.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Julian's answer, you can remap Alt use `xmodmap`:

```
xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Alt_L" -e "add mod4 = Alt_L"
```

This can go in your `.xinitrc` along with the call to `setxkbmap`.